# Connect points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to form a crystal

Tags: geometry, crystallography

This question is probably more programming oriented, but is theoretically a mathematical problem:
I consider $N$ points in space that describe the corners of a crystal. Since a plot of the points does not really help to capture the crystal, I want to connect the points. At first I thought about simply using the average distance between the points. Whenever the distance between two points is smaller than this average distance, a line should be drawn. As simple as that. Unfortunately, the crystal can also look a bit misshapen, see picture. Do you have a good principle in mind for me on how to connect these points?
[image]

Comment: It is just an idea, I am no expert in cristallography. But you could assign to each atom a number $k$ its coordination number and draw a line with each of its $k$ nearest neighbours!

Comment: The problem statement isn't very clear. caverac's answer gives an option, but I see a drawback to it: not all vertices are connected to something. Perhaps you would rather choose to keep the edges that are *not* part of the convex hull, but this also could fail spectacularly for regular crystals (like a cube for instance). Do you expect the crystals to have "internal" vertices or not? Is it ok to have unconnected vertices? Do you prefer edges on the periphery?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I completely understand the question, but I think what you're looking for is a [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull


# random points
np.random.seed(1)
points = np.random.uniform(size=(20, 3))

# convex hull
hull = ConvexHull(points)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

# points
ax.plot(points.T[0], points.T[1], points.T[2], "bo")

# edges
for s in hull.simplices:
    s = np.append(s, s[0])
    ax.plot(points[s, 0], points[s, 1], points[s, 2], "r-")
```

[image]